# JQuery removing wrong li

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following mark up:

```
<ul class="media-list">
  <li class="media post">
     <div class="media-body">
        <div class="post-content">
           <p>test</p>
        </div>
        <div class="post-files clearfix">
           <p>Attached Files</p>
           <ul class="list-inline">
             <li>
                <a class="js-delete-file" data-file-id="13" title="Delete" href="#">
                   <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
              </li>
           </ul>
        </div>
     </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

When I click js-delete-file anchor I want to remove the immediate li this link is inside.

The following Jquery is removing the li with class "media-post" instead. How do I remove the li the link is inside?

```
(".js-delete-file").click(function (e) {
    var a = $(this); // "this" is the <a>

     a.parents("li").fadeOut(function () {
            $(this).remove();
     });
});
```

Comment: put an alert before $(this).remove(); alert($(this).html()); to check the html selected by this line in  the Dom.

Comment: you can use parent() instead of parents().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to:

> get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

```
$(".js-delete-file").click(function (e) {
    var a = $(this); // "this" is the <a>

     a.closest("li").fadeOut(function () {
            $(this).remove();
     });
});
```

---

While [`.parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) is used to:

> Get the *ancestor**s*** of each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

---

You could also use [`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) *singular* in this particular case as well.

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the parent() method traverses to the immediate parent of each of these elements in the DOM tree and constructs a new jQuery object from the matching elements.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".js-delete-file").click(function (e) {
    var a = $(this).parent('li'); // "this" is the <a>

     a.fadeOut(function () {
            $(this).remove();
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="media-list">
  <li class="media post">
     <div class="media-body">
        <div class="post-content">
           <p>test</p>
        </div>
        <div class="post-files clearfix">
           <p>Attached Files</p>
           <ul class="list-inline">
             <li>
                <a class="js-delete-file" data-file-id="13" title="Delete" href="#">
                   <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true">Delete</i>
                </a>
              </li>
           </ul>
        </div>
     </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```